# What are some multivariate models with feature interactions

Tags: machine-learning, multivariate-analysis, predictive-models, multivariate-regression

I have dependent variable matrix $Y_{i,j}$ and feature matrix $X_{i,k}$. My objective is to predict each element of the vector $[y_{i,0},...,y_{i,J}]$ by using new observations of the features, $[x_{i,0},...,x_{i,K}]$, i.e. to estimate $Y_{i,j} = f(X_{i,k})$.

In my problem, all the dependent variables are closely related, and any given dependent variable is explained by a large number of the available features (so for any dependent variable, there aren't many redundant features). In addition, interactions between the features are likely to be important in predicting the response vector.

An example of the type of problem I'm facing would be if each dependent variable was the expected life span of various species of fish, and the features were water temperature, salt/fresh water binary, lake/ocean binary, binary for existence of particular predators, etc etc. We want a fast model that can mix these to predict each element of the vector.

There are many ways to tackle this problem. What I am interested in is what multivariate models exist that are both fast at run time (it's for a real time application) and can handle interactions. I am also looking for a model that is automated; automated variable selection and automated interaction selection. I am also looking an approach where the multivariate version generalizes better than simply fitting separate models for each $y_{.,j}$ (which could be achieved with splines, glms, etc).

The obvious answer is multivariate forests or multi-output neural nets, and so on. I'm looking for a faster approach; i.e. a model that doesn't have any sort of "deep" or iterative architecture that is computationally burdensome for large data (a multivariate model that's additive in transforms of features or feature interactions is ideal). A good answer is multivariate splines, looking for others.